# Optimize Performance of SQL Server (a lot of waiting tasks)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, load-balancing, database-administration

I have a problem with my database (Microsoft SQL Server), we have a lot of users using our API and this API makes a lot of queries to our database (it is normal because we are saving tracking data), we are using a load balancer for our API so we can handle a lot of requests but this gave us the problem that is that in the morning everything works ok but when the day is passing everything goes very slow, I reviewed the activity monitor (i am not a DBA but the team does not have one) and I noticed that when it goes slow is when waiting tasks are increasing, it is always bigger than 500 (the waiting tasks are always around 500-800), as a result of this I talked with my manager that also is not technical and we rented a server that only will run the database, these are the specs:

Specs of server:

- 128 ram,16 vcpus

[image: Server specs]

But the problem is the same:

[image: Actvity monitor of database]

**I looked at the task manager and I noticed that is not even using 100% of ram or cpu:**
[image: task manager]

so I want that an expert can recommend me what to do because I have the hardware and it is not improving :(, thanks in advance.

Some relevant info:

- Our API is using entity framework, I heard that using ADO.NET can improve this, is it true?
- Buying an azure SQL database tier Business-critical can solve our problem?
- We have de SQL Standard edition
- Properties of SQL INSTANCE:

[image: properties]
[image: Memory]
[image: Processors]
[image: Connections]
[image: Advance]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this problem recently on a sql server. Please search for lock contention in google. Your database is doing its job and needs to lock to do updates and inserts. This is needed  to maintain consistency of the data. This is a tradeoff between consistency and speed (=concurrency). You need to look at the application layer and try to make your transactions shorter. You should also look at your transaction isolation level. Serialisable is not always needed and is a bad choise when there is a lot of locking. Please seach for isolation levels an how to choose one.
Perhaps you should talk with your developers about READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT. In case you think about read_commited_snapshot take a look at tempdb usage which will get higher.
This is easier said than done. I know. If you can get the locks down, your server will automatically be faster. Thats why you do not see heavy usage of CPU and RAM. It's waiting most of the time. Optimize your transactions.

Try to make a performance baseline before doing changes so you can measure if changes have a possitive effect.

In short:

- check isolation level
- check your transactions
- make a baseline
- think about READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT
- check your indexes.
- feedback would be nice :-)

Comment: Here a interessting link you can check: https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/lck_m_u/

Comment: Very educative answer and elegant, I will take a look, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, we have used the READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT scope and our waiting tasks were reduced to 10-20.  We know the trade-off but for us and the requirement is more important speed than consistency. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 2):

When poorly implemented, Entity Framework can certainly put undue load on databases so that is one avenue to explore. However it really does need investigating for possible culprits and the specific optimizations to eliminate them.

The most common performance issues that I come across with EF are things like:

1. Lazy Load hits. This is where devs write a query to load entities, then iterate over them accessing related entities which triggers more SQL calls to load those individual entities. When run over Sets of entities this results in a LOT of unnecessary querying. Eager loading related entities (`Include`) where those entities are needed can replace these extra DB hits with JOINs. Better still, leveraging projection through `Select` can result in far more efficient queries.
2. Loading too much data, too often. Something as simple as misplaced `ToList` calls can mean locks on far more rows than are needed. This is commonly caused when developers face situations where they want to filter data on computed values (I.e. method results ect. that cannot be translated to SQL) and the "fix" is to add a `ToList` and then it magically works. Behind the scenes EF is materializing a lot of unfiltered data from the server to memory. The fix here is to re-hash the filtering so that more filtering gets down to the query to reduce the amount of data being pulled back.

Things like Generic Repository classes are a dead give-away for these types of issues where repositories return back entire entities or collections of entities where more efficient options are available.

Classic examples include:

- Getting an entity back only to check if it is null. (Use a `.Any()` query  instead)
- Getting a list of entities back just to get a count. (Use a `.Count()` query instead)
- Getting an entity where only a small number of columns are needed. (Use projection with `.Select()` instead)

EF can build very efficient queries, but when poorly implemented it can lead to DB interaction nightmares. Unfortunately without digging into the code and running alongside a profiler it isn't possible to list specific improvements that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I see a blocked transaction.  There will be a blocker.  If you find the head blocker is a query that can be optimized, that would be a place to start.  Are these simple, single query transactions or are they several queries in a transaction?  Are you doing something that forces inserts to be single threaded like getting the last id and adding 1 for a new id for the insert?  Does it have to block other transactions?

For example, in a busy database we processed new records.  We did a fast read to get the last record to process.  Then we used a where clause to only process records up to that record.  Otherwise, inserts would be blocked by the transaction until all records were processed.